# Slim.php `halt` method behaves differently than documented?

Tags: php, http, slim

Slim's documentation reads the following in regard to the framework's `halt` method:

> Halt
>
> The Slim application’s halt() method will immediately return an
>   HTTP response with a given status code and body. This method accepts
>   two arguments: the HTTP status code and an optional message. Slim will
>   immediately halt the current application and send an HTTP response to
>   the client with the specified status and optional message (as the
>   response body). This will override the existing \Slim\Http\Response
>   object.

e.g.

```
//Send a default 500 error response
$app->halt(500);

//Or if you encounter a Balrog...
$app->halt(403, 'You shall not pass!');
```

Because I'm having some problems in this area, I've built the following test application, according to their documentation:

```
<?php

// Include Slim framework dependencies;
require '../lib/Slim/Slim.php';

\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader(); // Slim's autloader;
$app = new \Slim\Slim();

//Send a default 500 error response
$app->halt(500);
```

And interestingly, the response I get is:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Slim\Exception\Stop' in D:\projects\myApplication\api\lib\Slim\Slim.php:1004 Stack trace: #0 D:\projects\myApplication\api\lib\Slim\Slim.php(1024): Slim\Slim->stop() #1 D:\projects\myApplication\api\app\app.php(10): Slim\Slim->halt(500) #2 D:\projects\myApplication\api\public\index.php(4): include_once('D:\__projects\S...') #3 {main} thrown in D:\projects\myApplication\api\lib\Slim\Slim.php on line 1004
```

Needless the say, the HTTP response code is 200. So what's going on with Slim, exactly? Why isn't the HTTP response code 500?

Comment: _“Why isn't the HTTP response code 500?”_ – because script execution got canceled at some point due to fatal error caused by the uncaught exception …?

Comment: In short: this appears to be, according to the Slim documentation, a complete example on how to use the `halt` method, which doesn't work as expected AND documented(!).

Comment: Well if you think their docs are faulty, then take that up with them …

Comment: Is the test application you posted the entirety of your code?  $app->halt() is intended to be called within a route, and I see neither a route nor $app->run() at the end of your script.

Answer (score 4):

It is not allowed to call halt() method outside of the route callback.
You should use like this;

```
$app->get('/method/', function () {
  //logical controls
  //do something
    //or
  $app->halt();
});
```

Comment: Plus, if you want to cancel in Middleware and send response early, set status with `$this->app->response()->setStatus()` in your Middleware class and don't call `$this->next()->call()`. [ref](http://help.slimframework.com/discussions/questions/170-halt-slim-application-in-a-middleware-class)