# Slim Framework middleware that selects a route

Tags: php, middleware, slim

How to select a route in a custom Slim middleware?
I would like to force a specific route, but I don't know how to do:

```
class Acl extends \Slim\Middleware{
    public function call()
    {
        if($isnotlogged){
            //force to select "login" route
            ...
        }
        $this->next->call();
    }   
}
```

Comment: I'd have thought the routing was already chosen at this point. Can you do a redirect instead, or do you particularly want to do an internal forwarding? (Have used Slim, but don't know whether this is possible).

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21881963/slim-php-only-catch-valid-routes-with-middleware

Comment: I can not redirect because I'm not inside a callback (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19654370/slim-php-halt-method-behaves-differently-than-documented). Route seems to be select on the last middleware call (Slim itself), I want to force the selection of the route

Comment: [This example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25110369/472495) appears to dispatch a custom route - worth a look?

Comment: I found another solution, but I had to change a visibility of  a \Slim\Router property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a working hack:

\Slim\Router $matchedRoutes property has a protected visibility, so I must create a custom Router to override it:

```
class MyRouter extends \Slim\Router {

    public function setRoute(\Slim\Route $route){
        $this->matchedRoutes=[$route];
    }

}
```

When I initialize Slim I have to set my Router:

```
$app = new \Slim\Slim();
$app->router=new MyRouter();
```

Finally I can force the route selection inside my middleware:

```
class Acl extends \Slim\Middleware{
    public function call()
    {
        if($isnotlogged){
            $this->getApplication()->router()->setRoute($this->getApplication()->router->getNamedRoute("login"));
        }
        $this->next->call();
    }   
}
```